# Windows 7 Performance Options - Visual Effects - custom settings to balance performance/appearance?

Tags: windows-7, performance, visual-effects

So I started a new job and my work PC is terrible. I'm talking 2GB of RAM... Having outlook, a few browser tabs and a few pdfs, and excel open will have my physical memory usage at 75%. My video driver repeatedly 'stops responding and has recovered'

I've played with changing the 'Visual Effects' in Windows 7. "Adjust for best appearance" will cause my pc to screech to a halt and my graphics card to crap out multiple times an hour. "Adjust for best performance" makes it difficult to read and create marketing materials because everything on my screen looks dog shit (no anti aliasing). I don't mind the windows 95 look, but one thing I can't stand about the "adjust for best performance" setting is that it breaks the ALT+TAB window switching - I can no longer use arrow keys to navigate the menu. Instead I have to use the 'xp' approach of switching icons/windows.. TAB for left and SHIFT+TAB for rightwards....

Which "custom" setting will fix this? and what are your favorite "custom" barebones settings for visual effects? (balancing performance and appearance).

Any input appreciated guys, thx...

Comment: You need more ram, this is the only real solution to your issue. 4gb minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "Adjust for best performance" and, in checkboxes, only check "Smooth edges of screen fonts, Show window contents while dragging, Use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop, and Use visual styles on windows and buttons".
Also, if you have a graphics card of +128mb, you can check "enable desktop composition" and "show shadows under windows".

Comment: Boom! this is exactly what I was looking for.  We'll see if my PC craps out under these settings, but this gives me a setting to chip away at.

Comment: PC crapped out 15 mins later for first time all day ;( ... will adjust from here though thanks!